# Casting Vector.<B> to Vector.<A>

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

`B` extends `A`.

How to cast?

I tried `myVectB as Vector.<A>`. But got null.

---

```
override protected function getItems():Vector.<JBuyable>
{
    return player.bonus as Vector.<JBuyable>; // null;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A banana **is-a** fruit. But a list of bananas **is-not** a list of fruit. Otherwise you could take your list of bananas, cast it to a list of fruit, and then add an apple.

Comment: if i will interate over the vector to make another one, i can put an apple there too.

Comment: If you make another one, yes. But you're not then corrupting your original list of bananas

Comment: you can use Vector of Interface if this conversion is not a rare one.

Comment: adding an apple to a list of fruit is fine; what should not be allowed is to convert a list of fruit to a list of bananas

Comment: the real answer here is not OOP related.  in as3... Vectors don't cast... period.  A Vector.<String> in not a Vector.<Object>  even though a String is an Object.  The base types must match exactly.

Comment: You can however do what @YordanYanakiev suggested and use Vector.<IBuyable> and both bananas and apples can go in it.  You just have to cast the items when using them... not the Vector.